# CSS animation is not working as i want it

Tags: html, css, animation

```css
.square3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f56d4a;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: shift;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  /* animation-direction: alternate; */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shift{
    from{
        left: 0;
    }to{
        left: 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="square3"></div>
```

View this pen to see what it's all about [This is the pen.](https://codepen.io/samuel_emeka/pen/bGrVBNx)

I want the box/div to shift to the right then come back to its normal state and I tried using transition property for the `left` but still it's not working as I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use percentage and set keyframes as below.

```css
.square3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f56d4a;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: shift;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
  /* animation-direction: alternate; */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes shift{
  0%   {left: 0px;}
  50%  {left: 100px;}
  100%  {left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
        <div class="square3"></div>
```

Comment: Whoa that worked thanks. I thought it would be a very hard thing to do but as it turned out not that hard.

Comment: @SamuelEmeka Please close the answer if your issue is resolved, you're welcome!

Comment: What do you mean close the answer